# Java: Shutdown without a volatile variable?

Tags: java, concurrency, signals, volatile, shutdown

Following scenario:

I have a application, which runs for weeks and then i want to shut it down gracefully.

The following code do the trick:

```
Main-Thread:

boolean volatile active=true;

while(active)
{
    //loop-code (very fast)
}


//shutdown-thread, called once after a few weeks

active=false;
```

So now after each loop-iteration, i have a look up in the main memory, cause of that volatile read (right?!).

And i dont want that, only for that shutdown after a few weeks.

Are there any other solution, that my main-thread get notified about that shutdown?

Any signal that goes directly into the main-thread-cache? so that it dont have to look-up itself in the main memory each time, but get notified from extern?

Or any other solution?

**Edit (integrate my own answer into this question):**

a possible solution could be, reducing the volatile access, see the following code:

```
boolean volatile active=true;


while(active)
{
    for(int i=0; i<100; ++i)
    {
        //loop-code
    }
}
```

so with that solution i can reduce the volatile reads, but i increase, after a shutdown the max loop-iterations from 1 to 100.

that solution decrease the volatile access, but dont eliminate it fully.

Comment: Is there a reason you are running your “very fast” code in a loop with no pauses?  That will use a tremendous amount of CPU.  Just how frequently does that loop-code need to execute?

Comment: that should underline, that my volatile active read is not negligible. if the code in the loop is slow, then: who cares about that volatile active read^^

Comment: Your assumption that volatile always reads from main memory is wrong. A cache-coherent system will read the volatile very quickly from L1 until another thread invalidates the cacheline on which the variable resides. Then, there will be a cache-to-cache transfer for the updated value.

Comment: oh ok, that sounds interessting; that means if  there is no volatile write, the overhead of a volatile exists only in reading from l1 cache. i guess a better optimiziation is not possible let taking different threads with each other (for example, a direct signal into the register?), maybe you can formulate this comment as answer, that invalidate the most of my question cause of a wrong assumption.

Comment: @Eric `volatile` reads are not expensive due to the cache or main memory, but due to the formal *happens-before* relationship they establish, which affects *all* reads within the loop. In theory, a JVM could optimize the effects away for the case that the loop repeatedly reads the same value, but to my knowledge, this does not happen with the HotSpot JVM.

Comment: @Holger, that's true. What if the above code relaxed the read with acquire mode (or even opaque)?

Comment: @Eric for a simple quit flag, opaque access would be enough and indeed have the lowest impact. But it requires at least Java 9.

Comment: @Holger what do you mean with that "all reads within the loop"? i thought that volatile means, that all reads in the loop must be before that volatile read, right? And what changes now that opaqueue mechanism by VarHandles? (should i ask this in a own question?)

Comment: @RobinKreuzer “before” is not a useful term considering that you are reading the `volatile` variable repeatedly, in every iteration. Normally, the JVM can optimize the code under the assumption that it is the only one modifying heap variables (i.e. ignore the possibility of changes by other threads), which allows to keep values in CPU registers, but also predict the outcome of conditionals in subsequent iterations based on the previous values and so on. The presence of the volatile read makes it consider potential changes made by the thread which performed the corresponding write.

Comment: As an extreme example, `for(int i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i++) heapVar++;` may get optimized to `heapVar += 1_000_000;` whereas `for(int i = 0; i < 1_000_000 && volatileBooleanFlag; i++) heapVar++;` will keep doing one million increments. This is not necessary, the semantics of this specific example would still allow doing `if(volatileBooleanFlag) heapVar += 1_000_000;`, but the HotSpot JVM is known to be very conservative when optimizing code including `volatile` reads and won’t do this.

Comment: ok i understand this.... and if i use that VarHandles get/setOpaque, then if(opaqueBooleanFlag){heapVar +=1_000_000} would be possible?, cause that opaque value only flushes its own value to the l1-cache/memory and not all others too?, so i have there no happens-before, but still an value (only the opaque-value itself) which is cache-coherent, right?

Comment: @Holger ping!^^

Comment: Basically, you’re description is right, the opaque mode ensures the visibility of the change, but has no impact on the other variables. As said, in theory, the described operation is possible for all modes here, but won’t happen in practice. The opaque mode is the weakest mode that still guarantees visibility. When a particular JVM still doesn’t optimize it, there’s no better solution anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption that a volatile read always hits main memory doesn't hold for cache-coherent systems. The volatile read should hit L1 until the other thread modifies the flag and invalidates the cacheline upon which the variable resides.

However, volatile reads establish a happens-before relation with subsequent accesses, so this prevents the compiler and CPU from performing certain latency-hiding tricks. Instead, use opaque access mode to lessen the impact (thanks Holger :)).

Something like this should be fast, though I'll leave the benchmarking up to you:

```
AtomicBoolean active = new AtomicBoolean(true);

while(active.getOpaque())
{
    //loop-code (very fast)
}


//shutdown-thread, called once after a few weeks

active.setOpaque(false);
```

If you're wondering what all these access modes are, here's a nice summary: [Using JDK 9 Memory Order Modes](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/html/j9mm.html).